# How to do this in a for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

This is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='index.css'>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="background-color:pink;"></div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:purple;"></div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:blueviolet;"></div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:rebeccapurple;"></div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:royalblue;"></div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:red;"></div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:green;"></div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color:greenyellow;"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want a for loop in php where there gets printed as many boxes as 'x' is. I have tried this:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
     echo "<div class="column" style="background-color:pink;"></div>";
}
```

But it's not echoing anything, and also, how do I make sure they all have a different background color when I echo?

Comment: Try `echo "<div class='column' style='background-color:pink;'></div>";` remember if `"` starts a string literal `"` will stop it

Comment: But as each of your hardcoded divs has a different colour, you will loose all that

Comment: can also use backslash \ to escape " : "<div class=\"column\" style=\"background-color:pink;\"></div>";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all colors in array and:

```
$colors = ['pink', 'purple', 'blue'];
foreach ($colors as $color) {
    echo '<div class="column" style="background-color:' . $color . ';"></div>';
}
```

Also note usage of `"` and `'` in `echo`.

Comment: Ha, beat me to it :)

Comment: LOL!!  You typed much faster than me.  Had the array down and then your answer popped-up.  :)